# Open an URL for a custom protocol from within Visual Studio Code

Tags: url, visual-studio-code

In our software we are using a custom protocol handler. An URL for this protocol looks like this:

```
xyz://foo/bar/action?SnVzdCBhIGR1bW15IHRleHQgZm9yIG15IFNPIFBvc3Q=
```

When I enter this URL in any browser on my system, it is correctly handeled by our software. Now I would like to open that URL from within VS Code with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click, just as I can do with, for example, `https`-Links.

Unfortunately VS Code doesn't recognize this as an URL. Is there some way to tell it that the above is a clickable URL?

Comment: Any chance you found an answer that you could share ?

Comment: @Uriel Unfortunately not ;-(

Comment: Possibly related: [`Navigator.registerProtocolHandler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler)

Comment: Is this still revelvant? And if yes, would a VSExtension a possible solution?

Comment: @Smartis Yes, I'd still like to have a solution for this and an extension would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a VS Code extension where you register your own link provider with `vscode.languages.registerDocumentLinkProvider`. The link provider will return a list of links.

Since custom protocols are not allowed in links, you can use "Command URIs" instead. For example:

```js
const args = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({x: ..., y: ...}));
const link = new vscode.DocumentLink(
    range, vscode.Uri.parse(`command:helloworld.mycmd?${args}`)
));
```

The `command:` part is fixed, whereas `helloworld.mycmd` is a command you need to register with

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.mycmd', myCmdHandler);
```

You control the args you send to your command, and you can do anything inside your command, so you can just call the app associated with `xyz://` directly by using, for instance, the following `shell` function:

```js
import * as cp from 'child_process';

function shell(cmd: string) {
    return new Promise<void>((res, rej) => {
        cp.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log('--- stdout ---\n' + stdout);
            console.log('--- stderr ---\n' + stderr);
            if (err) {
                rej(err);
            } else {
                res();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Feel free to modify it, of course.

**EDIT:** You can also just let the OS handle the URI. For instance, on Windows you can execute the shell command `start "" "xyz://..."`. Maybe node.js can do the same in a more platform-independent way.

Hopefully, I've given you enough pointers. You can use the [source code](https://github.com/dlevs/vscode-pattern-links) of the Link Patterns extension as a starting point.